# New line in the middle "data-label"

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, char

As the title suggests, I would like to know if anyone knows a way to write in a new line a text in the middle `"td data-label`".

I tried this:

```
<td data-label="Name ***\n*** (Other text)">Name</td>
<td data-label="Name ***<br/>*** (Other text)">Name</td>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Hi Ori Drori,

I need to write the entire header of a table in mobile device format.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I suggest asking about what you want to do, and not how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: I don't think it's a XY situation.

Please excuse me if I am not well explained.

I try to explain myself better ...

within this pseudo "data-label" element, I have a text that must necessarily be broken (one part in one line and the other below).

<td data-label = "1 line / 2 line">

Comment: It is another approach, but maybe it can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after